# Html page of single page application Omits HTML5 doc type. Are we going to suffer any penalties?

Tags: html

We are developing a rich single page web application by using requirejs, jquery and knockout. At early stages of our development we have missed the first and fore most HTML below doc type tag

Now after an year we realized this. Our application is targeted only on Chrome 18 version as our user machines have only Chrome 18.

Based on initial analysis and study we learned following points
1.  Not having doctype can cause browser to render the document in quirks mode and not standard mode.
2.  Quirks mode browser look and feel may be unpredicted and browser needs to work hard in order to render the page. 
3.  Chrome has quirks mode. Please refer the url (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode)

But at the same time We came to know from stack exchange post([Can you use HTML5 features without declaring the HTML5 DOCTYPE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248696/can-you-use-html5-features-without-declaring-the-html5-doctype#)).
- Webkit-browsers, Firefox and Opera will handle HTML5 elements quite normally even if your doctype is not HTML5

After reading stack exchange post, We are little confused. Now my question is

1. Omitting Doc type in our application cause to suffer our application any kind of penalties or negative impacts in terms of performance and memory leaks in Chrome 18 browser.
2. Even though if we don't have any penalties, having Doc type has provides any merits to our application in terms of performance and memory leaks in Chrome 18 browser.

**More Info Based on Comments:**
1. When I say penalties it is not about SEO issues. It is about performance and memory leaks etc...
2. We have done initial sanity tests and we see every thing is functional as expected. But unable to test performance and memory leak penalties.
3. Our application is intranet application and it is accessible only from our intranet net work.

Comment: If your question is will adding a doctype affect your web app, my answer is why don't you test it and see?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. SEO is off-topic.

Comment: @MarcB, I dis agree. It is not SEO related. Who told you it is SEO related

Comment: @j08691, We have tested. we found no immediate issues. But performance wise and memory leak wise we don't know how to test and see the impact

Comment: then don't talk about "penalties". talk about browser issues...

Comment: @MarcB: Penalty is not equal to SEO issues. At least any dictionary doesnt say it

Comment: This question is too broad to have an answer that could be reasonably determined to be correct. Too many what ifs and it is basically asking for advice.

Comment: @KarlAnderson, I  don't understand your point. I believe question is very specific to Chrome 18 and specific to Performance and memory leak issues. As per me it is very narrowed down specific question. Your comment is very subjective and generic. Please be specific

Comment: use webpagetest.org to test performance and memory leak issues on the client in a reproducible manner.

Comment: @pherris: Thanks for your suggestion. However Our application is intranet application and it is accessible only from our intranet net work. The webpagetest.org unable to access and hence reporting connection refused error

Comment: You can stand up a private instance (internal) if you like - https://sites.google.com/a/webpagetest.org/docs/private-instances

Comment: @Pherris: Thanks for your good and constructive suggestion. I appreciated it.